# Inserting selective columns to postgres using pandas python

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

Objective is to write excel column data into postgres table.But all the columns names in excel doesn't match with the table column.
So what I am doing is trying to insert only the common columns.
I am able to get the common data in the set.

I am stuck as to how to insert the data in a single query.

I am using pandas dataframe.

```
 #Getting table columns in a list
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, host=host, port=port, user=user, password=pwd)
    print("Connecting to Database")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM " + table_name + " LIMIT 0")
    table_columns = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
    #print table_columns

    #Getting excel sheet columns in a list
    df = pd.read_excel('/Users/.../plans.xlsx', sheet_name='plans')
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/test_db')
    column_list = df.columns.values.tolist()
    #print(column_list)
    s = set(column_list).intersection(set(table_columns))
    for x in df['column_1'] :
        sql = "insert into test_table(column_1) values ('" + x + "')"
        cur.execute(sql)
        cur.execute("commit;")

    conn.close()
```

update the code based on the answers but with this every time i run the program it inserts new records. Is there any option where I can just do the update.

```
 s = set(column_list).intersection(set(table_columns))

    df1 = df[df.columns.intersection(table_columns)]

    #print df1
    df1.to_sql('medical_plans', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, index_label=None)
```

Comment: Your SQL statement only inserts into one column `column_1`. Is that really what you want? Why don't you use Pandas `to_sql`?

Comment: How to insert values using to_sql with the values in the set and corresponding values in the dataframe. to_sql for me is generating a query containing all the excel columns

Comment: If the columns in your table have the same names as the columns of your dataframe you could do something like `df1 = df[df.columns.intersection(table_columns)]` in order to get the columns you're interested in. Then use `df.to_sql(table_name, con=engine)` to insert into SQL. Find more information [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

Comment: This helps. I used `df1.to_sql('medical_plans', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, index_label=None)`. This appends all the values even it is there in the table. And if I use `if_exists='replace'`, it fails when the table is already present . What can I use in such case.